# Strange behaviour with Jenkins' "Pipeline: Build Step" plugin

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to trigger Jenkins job with parameters from another job. I'm using this code for triggering:

```
stage ('Trigger autotests'){
  if (currentBuild.currentResult == 'SUCCESS'){
    build job: 'CloudVPN_Monitors/Monitor_QA', wait: false, parameters: [
      string(name: 'Environment', value: 'qa'),
      string(name: 'Browser', value: 'chrome')
    ]
 }
}
```

This peace of code works pretty well (in my test Jenkinsfile), job is triggered. But when I use the same code in my original Jenkinsfile - I'm getting error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[job:CloudVPN_Monitors/Monitor_QA, wait:false, parameters:[@string(name=Environment,value=qa), ...]]]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), take(int), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
```

Please take a look at my original Jenkinsfile:

```
#!groovy

properties([
    [$class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '10', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '10']]
]);

def agent = getAgentForBranch()

node(agent) {
    notifyBuild('STARTED')

    def node = tool name: 'NodeJS', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'
    env.PATH = "${node}/bin:${env.PATH}"

    sh 'npm --version'

    stage ('Checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }

    def date = new Date()
    def commitId = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --short --sq HEAD')
    def build = "${env.BUILD_NUMBER} | ${commitId} | ${date}"
    def RUNAUTOTESTS = false

    try {

        def IMAGE_ENVIRONMENT = env.BRANCH_NAME
        def WEBPACK_BUILD_ENV = env.BRANCH_NAME

        switch(env.BRANCH_NAME) {
            .......
            case 'qa':
                BUILD_ENVIRONMENT = 'qa'
                IMAGE_ENVIRONMENT = 'qa'
                AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1'
                RUNAUTOTESTS = true
                break;
            .......
        }

        CAPTCHA_PATH = '/cloudvpnui/' + BUILD_ENVIRONMENT


        stage ('Build docker containers'){
            withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'nexus-ovpn-ui-shared', variable: 'NPMRC')]){
                ........
            }
            withAWSParameterStore(credentialsId: 'aws-public-captcha', naming: 'basename', path: "${CAPTCHA_PATH}", recursive: true, regionName: "${AWS_REGION}") {
                ........
            }
        }

        stage ('Upload containers') {
            .........
        }

        stage ('Update AWS service') {
            .........
        }

        stage ('Clean docker image') {
            .........
        }

        if (RUNAUTOTESTS){
            stage ('Wait until service becomes stable'){
                sh "aws ecs wait services-stable --cluster cloudvpn-${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT} --services cloudvpn-ui-${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}"
                // Wait for ALB initialization
                sleep 120
            }
            stage ('Trigger autotests'){
                if (currentBuild.currentResult == 'SUCCESS'){
                    build job: 'CloudVPN_Monitors/Monitor_QA', wait: false, parameters: [
                        string(name: 'Environment', value: 'qa'),
                        string(name: 'Browser', value: 'chrome')
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (e) {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
        throw e
    } finally {
        notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
    }
}

def getAgentForBranch() {
    .......
}

def notifyBuild(String buildStatus = 'STARTED') {
    .......
}
```

Does enyone know what's going on? Why build fails with error?
Thanks!

P.S.
Jenkins v.2.204.1
Pipeline: Build Step plugin v.2.7

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error it seems that in the job `CloudVPN_Monitors/Monitor_QA` the mentioned parameters are not present. Try out below solutions.
1. Check if the mentioned parameters are presented in the jenkinsfile of the job that you are calling. 
2. Try removing `wait` and check if the error is going. 
3. Try out below command instead. It works for me.
`build(job: "<relative path>/<job>/<branchname>", parameters: [booleanParam(name: 'userFlag', value: true), booleanParam(name: 'prodFlag', value: false)], propagate: false, quietPeriod: 1)`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but error is not related to parameters itself. It tells, that Groovy can't find method 'build', instead of this method it offers wait(), any etc. I think, that it's a bug of Jenkins (or its particular job), as trigger with parameters works in clean test Jenkins job.